# sys.all_columns raises error:Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Arabic_CI_AS" in the equal to operation

Tags: sql-server, collation, sql-server-collation

I tried to change default collation of my SQL Server to the default one: "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" by this command:

```
sqlservr -m -T4022 -T3659 -s”MSSQLSERVER” -q”SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS”
```

After did this, the query

```
SELECT * FROM sys.all_columns
```

It does not work and raises an error:

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Arabic_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

I found out that the column which causes the error is `collation_name`.
Moreover, creating new databases also face a problem. I can not open "Tables" folder below the database name and that is because it uses the view `sys.all_columns` to open that folder.

How can I fix this problem?

I also tried this query:

```
SELECT COLLATION_NAME COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
FROM sys.all_columns
```

but it did not work.

I should say that the system databases have the default collation: `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`
also knowing this fact may help: There had been some databases with different collation before I changed the default collation and there were no error.

The last thing that I have found out is this view causes the error: `sys.system_components_surface_area_configuration`.

Comment: Why not set the collation on the database Level instead of trying to change the server collation? Server collation is set at the time of installation. Changing it after the installation will give you nothing but problems.

Comment: If you *really* need to change the server's collation, I really suggest that you reinstall SQL Server.

Comment: add a new instance, with the new collation. then it gets tricky, as you connect with pathon to the old collation make a new connection to the new collation and the transfer the data, that will keep the data

Comment: I did not know it may cause such problem. I guess I have to reinstall it :(

Comment: What happens if you run `DBCC CHECKDB` on those databases? Did you follow all the instructions here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/set-or-change-the-server-collation?view=sql-server-ver16#change-the-server-collation-in-sql-server for setting the server collation, including dropping all database and rebuilding `master`?

Comment: *Don't* try to hack the server collation to begin with, that will *guarantee* mangled data and the problems you describe. You can't just hack it with a command-line argument either. Collations are stored at the column level. What's the *actual* problem you want to solve? Why did you try to hard-code the collation?

Comment: SQL Server supports Unicode (nvarchar) fields whose contents aren't affected by the collation. You can store Arabic and Chinese content in the same `nvarchar` column no matter the collation. Collation does affect sorting and indexing though. You don't have to use the same collation in all databases and columns. You can specify different default collations for new databases. You can specify different collations for each column.

Comment: The only place the server and database collation may conflict is temporary tables, because tempdb uses the server's collation. You can overcome this if you use `COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT` when you define temporary tables or table variables

Comment: DBCC CHECKDB run successfully for all databases. Existed databases are fine. Just new databases have this problem and I figured out if I choose the collation manually, they will be all right as well. I suppose rebuilding the master database may resolve the issue. Thanks. I will mention the result.

Comment: I've read that paper about rebuilding the system databases. It is really complicated. I decided not to do it know. Maybe after I moved to another instance, I would.

Comment: Then you are going to have further issues. You need to rebuild `master` either way at this point.